# java - buffered reader helper class cant get second input

Tags: java

Struggling still with this after hours or research.. I have a simple helper class which is my first foray into try/catch error handling. I want to know if an input is valid against the type required and ask for a new input if it isn't... simple or so I thought. The class is being used in a simple term deposit calculator and is called multiple times (i.e. initial deposit, interest rate etc).

Here is the offending class, if this isn't sufficient to resolve I'll post up some additional snippets.

```
private Float inFloat;
private String temp;
private int inInt;
private String inString;
BufferedReader in = null;
boolean validInput = false;

public Float getFloat(String prompt) {
    validInput = false;
    do {
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.print(prompt);
            temp = in.readLine();
            inFloat = Float.valueOf(temp);
            validInput = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid float value");
        } finally {
            try {
                if (in != null) {
                    in.close();
                }
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } while (validInput == false);
    return inFloat;
}
```

**Update - Fixed!!!**

Thanks for the quick feedback... I managed to find another post that mentioned I shouldn't be closing off the BufferedReader and came up with the following adjustments so it now works. I'm now catching a NumberFormatException as well.. thanks for the tip :)

Not sure why it works now that I don't close off the BufferedReader... but I'll take the result!!

```
private Float inFloat;
private String temp;
private int inInt;
private String inString;
BufferedReader in = null;
boolean validInput = false;

public Float getFloat(String prompt) {
    validInput = false;
    do {
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.print(prompt);
            temp = in.readLine();
            inFloat = Float.valueOf(temp);
            validInput = true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid float value");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } while (validInput == false);
    return inFloat;
}
```

Comment: and what specific problems are you having with it? Note that Float.valueOf can throw exceptions other than IOException, and if it does, you won't catch them.

Comment: could you show a link to the suggestion to not close the reader? It doesn't make much sense, unless the `close` would affect  `System.in`.

Comment: @Andreas_D I, possibly incorrectly, intepretted that course of action from the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202060/issue-reading-input-from-java-system-in

Comment: ahh, learned something new, OK, don't close it. Makes sense. If you close the reader `in` then you send close signals to *all* underlying readers and streams - and so you close `System.in` with the effect, that it will not capture anymore console input. Thanks for the link!

Comment: but then, consider *not* creating a new buffered reader in every iteration, create it once outside the do...while loop. You can reuse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Float.valueOf(String s)` will throw a `NumberFormatException` if it can't parse the input. Catch that one in addition to `IOException`.

In your code, `NumberFormatException` is thrown (if the input is invalid) but not catched inside the method, so the method will return immediatly after completing the `finally` block.